# Spring 3 Security Authentication Success Handler

Tags: spring-security

I am using `form-login` for security and I am trying to implement an authentication success handler, but I am not sure how to go back to the resource that was initially requested before the login process. By default I think it implements a `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and I tried to mirror that class implementation. But it sets a `setDefaultTargetUrl(defaultTargetUrl)` and perhaps thats where the magic happens that it remembers the resource to go back to after the login process.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is my spring security `<form-login/>` element

```
<form-login login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/b2broe_login"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="passwordExpiredHandler" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?loginfailed=true" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resuming of the initial request is implemented in the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, which is used by default by `<form-login>`.

Comment: I see it needs a `HttpSessionRequestCache`. How is that set?

Comment: Got it working. Didn't need to worry about HttpSessionRequestCache.